# How to resolve don't flush the Session after an exception occurs

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, grails-orm

This is my code

```
try {
  if(request.currentOrganization) {
    Test test = new Test()
    test.organization = request.currentOrganization
    test.save()
  }
} catch(Exception ignoreMe) {
     //println("Unable to update notification table : " + ignoreMe.message)
}
```

And there is no need for this expection here, looking so strange, some of other answer for this topic didn't helped me, can someone help me to sort out this

**Exception**

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.rwi.base.test entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs
```

Comment: First of all why are you not using term called `Encapsulation`? and second at least post code of `DailyServiceNotification`

Comment: I mean getter/setter for organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your `request.currentOrganization` is detached from hibernate session. To fix it you can use:

```
def organization = Organization.get( request.currentOrganization.id )
notification.organization = organization
```

Comment: Your answer making some point, this is happening in live not in local, so let me check, also just see the expection. The point which rises the exception in different place and that exception is the root cause for this error

Comment: what's hapenning here `com.rwi.messaging.CommentThreadService.getAllItemForType(CommentThreadService.groovy:242)` ?

Comment: But that is working fine in local and in live no issue(code itself self-explainatory, with available comment type we getting all comments), but this is the place I have to check I think, also do you having any idea about withNewSession

Comment: the method name is self-explainatory indeed, nevertheless it's throwing an assertFailure, that's why I asked about it. And yes, I have an idea about `withNewSession` and it's pretty simple: it has relatively small field of use

Comment: so if I am using like DailyServiceNotification notification = new DailyServiceNotification() notification.withNewSession {
    notification.organization = request.currentOrganization
    notification.save() }, whether that is a bad code, or is it recommended?

Comment: You can use pretty much everything ;) the question is, how simple it would be at the end of the day. In your code example `withNewSession` is not necessarily required. `Notification.get( request.currentOrganization.id )` would re-attach your object to hib-session with no low-level code. If you have a feeling that the hib-session is not there, you can use `DailyServiceNotification.withTransaction{ .. }`

Comment: ok, thanks for your time and I will try that, may be in some time I'll remove some of my code 'cause those are confidentially

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that you have certain filed in `DailyServiceNotification` which is `null` in Java and you are trying to persist it but respective column is `NOT NULL` in database.

Comment: Yes you are right I think, but some solution will help me